# Parsing HTML getElementsByTagName not returning all cells

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, getelementsbytagname

I have some code that use to work to scrape data from a webpage however the webpage has changed and can no longer get it to work. The code is supposed to do calculations on the insider transaction table however `getelementsbytagname("td")` no longer returns all cells.

I'm guessing it's because it is a page embedded in a page or something but I cannot for the life of me resolve it, I am not very familiar with html. A sample webpage is `gurufocus.com/stock/lmb/insider`.

My code is below:

```
Sub getStatements()
    Dim wb As Object
    Dim doc As Object
    Dim incomeStmtURLs As Variant
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim allCells As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim aCell As HTMLTableCell
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim loginBoxData As String    

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Call ToggleEvents(False)

    incomeStmtURLs = Range("Sheet1!h1:h2").Value

    For i = 1 To UBound(incomeStmtURLs)
        Set wb = CreateObject("internetExplorer.Application")
        sURL = incomeStmtURLs(i, 1)

        wb.navigate sURL
        wb.Visible = False

        While wb.Busy
            Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#
            DoEvents
        Wend

        'HTML document
        Set doc = wb.document

        On Error GoTo err_clear

        ' gets all cell and looks for date format,
        ' goes from new transaction to old so once gets to older than a year it exits for loop
        ' checks nextSibling from date is a buy and if so does calculations, by taking further value sin row
        ' for priceThisTime have to get rid of $ symbol for calculation
        Set allCells = doc.getElementsByTagName("td")
        For Each aCell In allCells
            MsgBox (aCell.innerText)
            If aCell.innerText Like "####-##-##" = True Then
                If CDate(aCell.innerText) >= Date - 365 Then
                    If aCell.NextSibling.innerText = "Buy" Then
                        buys = buys + 1
                        sharesThisTime = CDec(aCell.NextSibling.NextSibling.innerText)
                        priceThisTime = aCell.NextSibling.NextSibling.NextSibling.NextSibling.innerText
                        totalPrice = totalPrice + (sharesThisTime * CDec(Right(priceThisTime, Len(priceThisTime) - 1)))
                        shareCount = shareCount + sharesThisTime
                    End If
                Else
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next aCell

        Sheet6.Cells(i + 1, 2) = buys
        If (shareCount <> 0) Then
            Sheet6.Cells(i + 1, 3).Value = totalPrice / shareCount
        End If

        buys = 0
        totalPrice = 0
        shareCount = 0

err_clear:
        If Err <> 0 Then
            Err.Clear
            Resume Next
        End If
        wb.Quit
    Next i

    Call ToggleEvents(True)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following targets specifically that table and retrieves all td elements. I think your logic could probably be applied on a column number basis but anyway (just in case I set the table into a variable as well).

I set the results per page to 100 but you can comment out that line

```
Option Explicit
'VBE > Tools > References:
' Microsoft Internet Controls

Public Sub GetData()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, lastDropDrownItemIndex As Long, dropDown As Object, t As Date
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10


    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.gurufocus.com/stock/lmb/insider"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        t = Timer

        Do
            Set dropDown = .document.querySelectorAll(".el-dropdown-menu__item")
            lastDropDrownItemIndex = dropDown.Length - 1
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
        Loop While lastDropDrownItemIndex < 1

        If dropDown.Length = 0 Then Exit Sub

        dropDown.item(lastDropDrownItemIndex).Click 'comment me out if don't want 100 results per page

        Dim tds As Object, table As Object
        Set tds = .document.getElementsByClassName("data-table")(0).getElementsByTagName("td")
        Set table = .document.getElementsByClassName("data-table")
        Stop
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Let me know how this goes

Comment: This is amazing thank you. I didn't know the table was called "data-table" I had been trying to refer to it as "normal-table data-table" previously. You can see why I thought that looking at the html! I'm pretty ignorant when it comes to this stuff. You also solved my next problem, changing the table to 100 rows. Thanks.

Comment: I don't completely understand but sometimes it gets stuck in the Do Loop While that you have made for the dropdown, the value of lastDropDownItemIndex appears to always be 11 however if I use dropDown.item(11).click this doesn't work. Do you know of a way around this. Thanks again.

Comment: I assume that for some reason the table is not loading. I have added a timeout so that if not loaded after 10 seconds program will safely exit. You need to explore what is going on on the page when it gets stuck. I assumed a table would always be present.

Comment: If you can find a way for me to replicate the problem I will debug from my end.

Comment: You are right it is because there was no table. One last question for you, in my code after Set tds = .document.getElementsByClassName("data-table")(0).getElementsByTagName("td") I have found I need to put a pause in currently I use Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:6")) I have found 6 is the best so far, if I put in less or no pause sometimes the results come up blank when they shouldn't do. Do you have a recommendation to get around this as waiting for 6 secs when you scraping thousands of webpages obviously has a big impact? Thanks.

Comment: You have the pause after the Set line? Or before?

Comment: after the set, in my head it doesn't have enough time to assign all the cells but im most probably wrong

Comment: The assignment is already done at the Set line. If you do debug.print tds.length immediately after the set line what do you see? If it entirely possible the elements, unpopulated are there. In which case we have other options.

Comment: If I enter debug.print tds.length immediately after the set it says 0, add it again immediately after my pause (which is the next line) it says hundreds

Comment: Ok. I’ll update later today and drop you a line so we can test if that’s ok?